# Python list with Vcenter vm

Tags: python, list, vcenter

I found a Python script to list all Vcenter VM attributes, but now I need to register some of attributes into a Python list (or array, dict... ).

But it doesn't works.

My getVminfos.py :

EDIT : the right file :

```
import argparse
import atexit
import itertools
import unicodedata
import pyVmomi
from pyVmomi import vmodl
from pyVmomi import vim

from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect

def GetArgs():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process args for retrieving all the Virtual Machines')
   parser.add_argument('-s', '--host', required=True, action='store',help='Remote host to connect to')
   parser.add_argument('-o', '--port', type=int, default=443, action='store',help='Port to connect on')
   parser.add_argument('-u', '--user', required=True, action='store',help='User name to use when connecting to host')
   parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', required=False, action='store',help='Password to use when connecting to host')
   args = parser.parse_args()
   return args


def print_vm_info(virtual_machine):
    """
    Print information for a particular virtual machine or recurse into a
    folder with depth protection
    """

    Ansible_Hosts = []
    Ansible_Groups = []
    Ansible_Names = []

    summary = virtual_machine.summary
    print("Name       : ", summary.config.name)
    print("Template   : ", summary.config.template)
    #print("Path       : ", summary.config.vmPathName)
    print"Guest      : ", str(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', summary.config.guestFullName))
#print("Instance UUID : ", summary.config.instanceUuid)
#print("Bios UUID     : ", summary.config.uuid)

print"State      : ", summary.runtime.powerState
if summary.guest is not None:
    ip_address = summary.guest.ipAddress
    if ip_address:
        Ansible_Hosts.append([ip_address])
        print "Ansible_Hosts[1:15]", Ansible_Hosts[1:15]


def main():
    args = GetArgs()

    try:
        si = SmartConnect(host=args.host,user=args.user,pwd=args.password,port=int(args.port))
        if not si:
            print("Could not connect to the specified host using specified "
             "username and password")
            return -1

        atexit.register(Disconnect, si)

        content = si.RetrieveContent() # get root folder

        container = content.rootFolder  # starting point to look into
        viewType = [vim.VirtualMachine]  # object types to look for
        recursive = True  # whether we should look into it recursively
        containerView = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
        container, viewType, recursive)

        children = containerView.view
        for child in children:
            print_vm_info(child)
    except vmodl.MethodFault as error:
        print("Caught vmodl fault : " + error.msg)
        return -1

    return 0

# Start program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Prints works like a charm, but always my lists (`Ansible_Hosts`, ...) are empty...

Answer (score -1):

The lists initialization statements (Ansible_Hosts = [] etc.) should go to main()